# REceiving SQL erro 37000 after attempting to run Script creating Trigger

Tags: sql, error-handling, triggers, dbeaver, intersystems-cache

I'm attempting to create a trigger using DBEAVER and Intersystems Cache Database using the following statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AFTER INSERT trigger1
    ON System.get_table1
    
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM System.get_table2 
END;
```

and im getting this error:

```
SQL Error [1] [37000]: [SQLCODE: <-1>:<Invalid SQL statement>]
[Location: <Prepare>]
[%msg: < 'BEFORE' or 'AFTER' expected, INSERT found^CREATE TRIGGER AFTER INSERT>]
```

I've attempted moving the `AFTER INSERT` around and it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Try with: `CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 AFTER INSERT ON ...` based on some general trigger [info here](https://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_createtrigger)